# cannot find pthread.c in linux folder

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I have downloaded kernel and the kernel resides in folder called Linux-2.6.32.28 in which I can find /Kernel/Kthread.c
I found Kthread.c but I cannot find pthread.c in Linux-2.6.32.28
I found Kthread.c in Linux-3.13/Kernel and Linux-4.7.2/Kernel

locate pthread.c finds file pthread.c in Computer/usr folder that comes when I install Ubuntu but pthread.c is not available in downloaded folders Linux-2.6.32.28, Linux-3.13, Linux-4.7.2

MORE: There are two sets of function calls. 1. System Calls 2. Library Calls.

For a computer to do any task it has to use hardware resources. So, how library calls differ from system calls?

System calls always use kernel which means hardware.
Library calls means no usage of kernel or hardware?

I know that library calls sometimes may resolve to system call.

What I want to know is that, if every set of function calls uses hardware then to what degree system calls will use hardware resources when compared with library calls and vice-versa.

Whether a function call is System or Library, at least hardware resource like RAM has to be utilized. Right?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the Pthreads implementation on GNU / Linux (such as Ubuntu) is part of the C library, glibc, not part of the kernel.

Comment: pthread library is implemented in user space using futex(2) system call of the Linux kernel. If you want to look at the code, you can check here https://github.com/lattera/glibc/tree/master/nptl for GNU Libc implementation and here https://github.com/wermut/musl/tree/master/src/thread for musl implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Read first [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html). It explains you that pthreads are implemented in the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) as [nptl(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/nptl.7.html).

The C standard library is the cornerstone of Linux systems, and you might have several variants of it; however, most Linux distributions have only one libc, often the [GNU glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/), which contains the NPTL. You might use another C standard library (such as [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) or [dietlibc](https://www.fefe.de/dietlibc/)). With care, you can have several C standard libraries co-existing on your system.

The C standard library (and every [user-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) program) is using [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to interact with the kernel. They are listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). BTW most C standard library implementations on Linux are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study (or even improve) their source code if you want to. You often use a system call thru the small wrapper C function (e.g. [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)) for it in your C standard library, and even more often thru some higher-level function (e.g. [fprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fprintf.3.html)) provided by your C standard library.

Pthreads are implemented (in the NPTL layer of glibc) using low-level stuff like [clone(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) and [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html) and a bit of assembler code. But you generally won't use these directly unless you are implementing a thread library (like NPTL).

Most programs are using the `libc` and linking with it (and also with [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0)) as a shared library, which is `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` on my Debian/Sid/x86-64. However, you might (but you usually don't) invoke system calls directly thru some assembler code (e.g. using a `SYSCALL` or `SYSENTER` machine instruction). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46646824/841108).

---

The question was edited to also ask

> What I want to know is that, if every set of function calls uses hardware then to what degree system calls will use hardware resources

Please read a lot more about [operating systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system). So read carefully [*Operating Systems: Three Easy pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (a freely downloadable textbook) and read about [Instruction Set Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) and [Computer Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture). Study several of them, e.g. [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) and [RISC-V](https://riscv.org/) (or [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture), [PowerPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC), etc...). Read about [CPU modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_modes) and [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

You'll find out that the OS manages physical resources (including RAM and [cores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor) of processors). Each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). So *from a user-space point of view*, a process don't use *directly* hardware (e.g. it runs in virtual address space, not in RAM), it runs in some [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) (provided by the OS [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system))) defined by the system calls and the ISA (the [unpriviledged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_(computing)) machine instructions).

> Whether a function call is System or Library, at least hardware resource like RAM has to be utilized. Right?

Wrong, from a user-space point of view. All hardware resources are (by definition) managed by the operating system (which provides [*abstractions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)) thru system calls). An ordinary application [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) program uses the abstractions and software resources ([files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file), processes, [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), [memory mappings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file), virtual address space, etc etc...) provided by the OS.

<sup>(so several books are required to really answer your questions; I gave some references, please follow them and read a lot more; we can't explain everything here)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your second cluster of questions: Everything a computer does is ultimately done by hardware.  But we can make some distinctions between different *kinds* of hardware within the computer, and different kinds of programs interacting with them in different ways.

A modern computer can be divided into three major components: central processing unit (CPU), main memory (random access memory, RAM), and "peripherals" such as disks, network transceivers, displays, graphics cards, keyboards, mice, etc.  Things that the CPU and RAM can do by themselves without involving peripherals in any way are called *computation*.  Any operation involving at least one peripheral is called *input/output* (I/O).  All programs do some of both, but some programs mostly do computation, and other programs mostly do I/O.

A modern operating system is also divided into two major components: the *kernel*, which is a self-contained program that is given special abilities that no other program has (such as the ability to communicate with peripherals and the ability to control the allocation of RAM), and is responsible for supervising execution of all the other programs; and the *user space*, which is an unbounded set of programs that have no such special abilities.

User space programs can do computation by themselves, but to do I/O they must, essentially, ask the kernel to do it for them.  A *system call* is a request from a user-space program to the kernel.  Many system calls are requests to perform I/O, but the kernel can also be requested to do other things, such as provide general information, set up communication channels among programs, allocate RAM, etc. A *library* is a component of a user space program.  It is, essentially, a collection of "functions" that someone else has written for you, that you can use as if you wrote them yourself.  There are many libraries, and most of them don't do anything out of the ordinary.  For instance, [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) is a library that (provides functions that) compress and uncompress data.

However, "the C library" is special because (on all modern operating systems, *except* Windows) it is responsible for interacting directly with the kernel.  Nearly all programs, and nearly all libraries, will not make system calls themselves; they will instead ask the C library to do it for them.  Because of this, it can often be confusing trying to tell whether a particular C library function does all of its work itself or whether it "wraps" one or more system calls.  The pthreads functions in particular tend to be a complicated tangle of both.  If you want to learn how operating systems are put together at their lower levels, I recommend you start with something simpler, such as how the `stdio.h` "buffered I/O" routines (`fopen`, `fclose`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `puts`, etc) ultimately call the `unistd.h`/`fcntl.h` "raw I/O" routines (`open`, `close`, `read`, `write`, etc) and how the latter set of functions are *just* wrappers around system calls.

(Assigning the task of wrapping system calls to the runtime library for the C programming language is a historical accident and we probably wouldn't do it that way again if we were going to start over from scratch.)

Comment: BTW, on SunOS5 and probably some Solaris, there is a `libsys` wrapping *only* system calls (and `errno`)

Answer (score 0):

pthread is POSIX thread. It is a library that helps application to create threads in OS. Kthread in kernel source code is for kernel threads in linux.

POSIX is a standard defined by IEEE to maintain the compatibility between different OS.

So pthread source code cannot be seen in linux kernel source code.

you may refer this link for pthread source code http://www.gnu.org/software/hurd/libpthread.html

Comment: The link refers to Hurd libc, not a linux one.